# Jquery accordion is working on my computer but not on server

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins, accordion

I'm having problems with jquery accordion together with jquery slider. The jquery slider is nested inside the accordion.

On my computer this works fabulously (even though IE gives some problems).

I uploaded on the server and it forms up the accordion links but these do not open when u click on them!!. any ideas?

[link](http://www.ocdmonline.org/michael/literature.php) **Username**:Testing **password**: test123

This seems to be also a problem which i'm having with ical calendar as well  in index.php (which runs perfectly on my computer but not online.

Comment: WFM. Can't reproduce your problem at all (accordions open, slider works)

Comment: What browser/version is it not working on? Works for me on Chrome, Safari and Firefox. Don't test or care about IE compatibility anymore.

Comment: I wish I had the luxury of not caring about IE. My analytics tell me a good majority of my clients still use it.

Comment: it was a stylesheet problem and some problem on the server coz now it's working properly as well here. i twasn't working  in all 3 browsers no matter what. i uploaded the styleshhet once again and it started to work

Answer (score 1):

Resolved : Stylesheet problem regarding font sizes and all

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be working fine for me.

Have you tried clearing your cache (CTRL+F5 does a force refresh on Windows machines)?